# Document name conventions of BaseX XML Database

Tags: xml, database, basex

What are the document name conventions of BaseX XML Database

Can the document names have characters such as @, / etc.

Answer (score 1):

Though the question is quite old now for archive reasons: BaseX Database must match the regular expression `[_-a-zA-Z0-9]+` as stated in the [documentation](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Databases).